# preventDefault() not working with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The `preventDefault()` isn't working and I have no clue why!

I checked other forums and this should be working

I also tried `$(document).ready(function() )` but that didn't work either.

The javascript and html are in that exact order if it makes a difference.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#my_form").submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
 var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
 var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
 var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

 $.ajax({
     url : post_url,
     type: request_method,
     data : form_data
 }).done(function(response){ //
     $("#server-results").html(response);
 });




});
```

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="http://link.php">
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_post" value="Post" >
</form>

<div id="server-results"></div>
```

thanks

Comment: "Isn't working..." what happens instead? Are there error messages in the console?

Comment: most likely `$("#my_form")` is returning 0 elements, thus no events are even being bound. (so event.preventDefault isn't even being ran, and your title is wrong)

Comment: What event are you trying to stop? The reload?

Comment: have you tried $("#my_form").on('submit',(function(event){

Comment: @Brian eh, that's identical to `.submit(...)`

Comment: Hi, thanks! The issue is that I don't want the page to be redirected to link.php

Comment: How to annoy javascript developers:  *"The java and html ..."*   :D

Comment: i don't see any java

Comment: Move the script to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Jasen I tried that and the form won't even work. The submit button didn't do anything

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to the code you have provided. Several of the suggested solutions would have solved your problem, but you state that they don't. Your problem is probably elsewhere. Like an incorrect ID, or incorrect script include, or a typo somewhere causing all of the code to not run, etc.

Comment: Kevin, any idea where?

Comment: well, on the page, but otherwise no. Could be a large number of things. Open the console and start digging.

Comment: If the submit button didn't do anything then `.preventDefault()` is working.

Comment: Jasen, I need the data to be submitted to Ajax l, just not for the page to be redirected

Comment: Try changing to just `$("#my_form").submit(function(){`  (remove `event` from the args).

Comment: Add `return false;` after the ajax call instead of using event.preventDefault.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried it and it still doesn't work. Have you checked if it works? You can copy paste the code

Comment: I can copy the code you say?  Let me try that: https://jsfiddle.net/cbjgqsdq/  ... and ... there's nothing wrong with your code - as stated by @KevinB.

Comment: What do you get with `alert($("#my_form").length)` (when added to the code directly infront of `$("#my_form").submit(...`  (don't run it in the console).

Comment: @freedomn-m What????? Did you get the input in the server-results div? What program did you use?

Comment: Have you tried with event delegation:  `$(document).on("submit", "#my_form", function() ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah, I did try that

Comment: See the link - there's two forms, one gives an error (without the handler) as it has nowhere to post to.  The other, which uses your code as-is (minus the irrelevant ajax), does not give an error which shows that the submit is being blocked.

Comment: Coming back to this - what do you get with the alert I suggested? Add it twice: `alert($("#my_form").length); $("#my_form").submit(function(event){ alert($("#my_form").length); }`?   If you get the first one with "0" then there's a problem with the selector and/or order of actions (ie the form doesn't exist when the code runs).  If you get the second alert then the `preventDefault` is working correctly and the issue is with the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Your comments above are not clear as to exactly what the problem is (whether the submit handler is being called or not or if it's just the ajax call that's the problem).

Answer (score -2):

Pls try $("#my_form").on('submit', function(event){});